# How to solve "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've done hours and hours of searching and still no luck (read a lot of stackoverflow as well).

I am trying to implement [FDTake](https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake) via Cocoapods. When I try and run it I get the following:

```
 undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FDTakeController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in VendeViewController.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I know there is many similar questions around  SO but all their solutions don't seem to work for me.

Comment: Id say the build settings for this component do not cover x86_64 (this is only on builds for the simulator, yes?)
If its an open source thing and you have the code then you can alter the build settings, but if its a compiled lib / framework then you'll need to contact the developers

Comment: @Jef nope, it doesn't work for devices either :(

Answer (score 0):

From the logs I can assume that you would be using a static library which is not build for simulator(architecture x86_64).

The library is only compiled for device and it needs to be complied and build for simulator also. Then the two static files (one abc.a for device and one abc.a for simulator) needs to be fat file i.e these files should be merged together using lipo command on terminal to create a fat file. Now when you use this fat file it will work both for simulator as well as device.

But the important thing is that you should have the source to compile and build the static libraries for simulator and device. After which you merge these to create a fat file which will work on all the defined architectures.

In case you are using third party static library (SDK) then you need to contact the respected party.